# Having issues with parsing Json file and setting vx and vy values in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having issues in parsing a json file with d3.json() function and adding the objects into a node tree. When I try to add them to the simulation I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'vx' on string".

I have tried looking into some examples and similar issues, but most of them don't use the json function to get the data. There was a suggestion to add the line "force('link').links(graph.links) before forceManyBody but I got the error "Cannot read property 'links' of undefined".

```
var width = window.innerWidth
var height = window.innerHeight


const svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("viewBox",[-width/2,-height/2,width,height]);


var linkForce = d3.forceLink().id(function(d){return d.name;});

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()

.force('link', linkForce)
.force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-120))
.force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json("secretSanta.json", function(error, graph) {

simulation.nodes(graph.nodes);
simulation.force('link').links(graph.links)
}
```

I been able to make d3 the properties of x and y coordinates to elements in the arrays using nodes and links as variables in the code, however they're not being added now for some reason. Not sure if I miss a step because I'm parsing a Json file. Here's the json file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gracemarod/Node-Graph/master/secretSanta.json.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of d3 are you using?

Comment: Currently I'm using d3 version 4